# install JayDeBeApi on WIndows 7

Tags: python, pip, jaydebeapi

I'm using python version 3.6.I'm trying to install JayDeBeApi on my windows 7.I used following command from my command prompt running in administrator mode

```
 pip install JayDeBeApi
```

But I'm getting following error

```
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
```

Can you please help me to rectify this error?

Comment: `Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored` is a warning, not an error. What is the error? Can we see the entire traceback?

Comment: For me it also hangs on the entire script. And I am not installing JayDeBeApi, but rather various other packages using pip.